# How to apply CSS styles to content rendered after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, templates, ecmascript-6

I'm writing an app which grabs a bunch of JSON data via AJAX, then renders the view which is constructed from the same data in an es6 template literal. Really simple version to demonstrate:

```js
let mountPoint = document.getElementById("mountPoint");
let view = document.createElement("section");
view.id = "view";
view.innerHTML = `<section>${returnedAjaxData}</section>`;
mountPoint.innerHTML = view;
```

```css
#mountPoint {
  background: #000000;
}

#view {
  background: #444444
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="mountPoint"></section>
</body>
</html>
```

Where ${returnedAjaxdata} is the data returned from the Ajax call (not shown here but working fine)

The problem is that "#mountPoint" has a black background but "#view" does not have a grey background. It seems that the CSS file is run before the "#view" renders since it waits for the Ajax data before rendering.

**EDIT**
I know how to change CSS on AJAX success for a specific element. My question is how do I run the entire stylesheet after the AJAX call returns AND the DOM is rendered. For context - the entire app will be inside "#mountPoint" so updating a single element wont help much

One possible solution would be to write the styles.min.css file after "#view" is rendered but that seems hacky... I'm wondering: how does React and other view rendering frameworks do this? They render HTML after the CSS files are read as well right? Is there a good pattern out there for this which I can learn?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: Changing the CSS on an element loaded with ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866043/jquery-changing-the-css-on-an-element-loaded-with-ajax)

Comment: I dont think it is. That answer references how to change a single element, I need the whole stylesheet to run after the AJAX call returns and the innerHTML is rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Element#innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) parses a string, and sets it as the html content of a node. The node you've created using [Document#createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) is not a string. When you try to add it to `mountPoint` using Element#innerHTML, it's converted to string, and the string doesn't have the id `view`.

You need to append the node to the view using [Node#appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or [ParentNode#append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) (not supported by MS browsers).

In addition css selectors (id for example) are case sensitive, and `mountpoint` in the css is not the same as `mountPoint` in the html.

```js
let mountPoint = document.getElementById("mountPoint");
let view = document.createElement("section");
view.id = "view";
view.innerHTML = `<section>returnedAjaxData</section>`;
mountPoint.appendChild(view); // append as a child of mountPoint
```

```css
#mountPoint { /** renamed to mountPoint **/
  height: 40px; /** just for the example **/
  background: #000000;
}

#view {
  background: #444444
}
```

```html
<section id="mountPoint"></section>
```

If the id in the CSS and the HTML are exactly the same Element#innerHTML will work as well:

```js
let mountPoint = document.getElementById("mountPoint");
mountPoint.innerHTML = '<section id="view">returnedAjaxData</section>';
```

```css
#mountPoint { /** renamed to mountPoint **/
  height: 40px; /** just for the example **/
  background: #000000;
}

#view {
  background: #444444
}
```

```html
<section id="mountPoint"></section>
```

Comment: Parentnode.append() doesnt work in IE, Edge or Safari https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it works for my example. It still doesnt work for my actual app because I need to append an HTML string to  the view node and appendChild needs a DOM node not a string

Comment: As long the selector (id) is similar, it works with innerHTML as well. See addition to answer.